# Make a series of points curl

Tags: graphics, geometric-transform

Say I have a series of points that make a straight line... (Fig 1)

```
points = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 0}}
```

I can rotate these points about the Z axis using a RotationTransform. (Fig 2)

```
r = RotationTransform[10 Degree, {0, 0, 1}]
r[points]
```

However, if I wanted to make the line curl, with each point rotating by a relative 10 Degrees to the point next to it, how would I map the RotationTransform across the list please? (Fig 3)

[image]

EDIT: An important thing to note is that the relative distance between each segments should remain constant at 1 unit after the rotations.  I could have made this clearer above apologies.

Comment: An aside: instead of typing out a list of regularly spaced vectors along the x-axis, consider `pts = Array[{#, 0, 0} &, 5];`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I normally use table so good to see a neater way of doing this...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Rotation about the origin

```
MapIndexed[N@Nest[r, #1, First[#2-1]] &, points]
```

> ```
> {{0., 0., 0.}, {0.984808, 0.173648, 0.}, {1.87939, 0.68404, 0.}, {2.59808, 1.5, 0.}, {3.06418, 2.57115, 0.}, {3.21394, 3.83022, 0.}}
> ```

```
ListPlot[%[[All, {1, 2}]]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

the norm of the vectors is conserved.

### Rotation about the last point

Ok, with the new request, rotating with respect of the last point

```
Accumulate@Prepend[MapIndexed[N@Nest[r, #1, First[#2]] &, Differences@points],First[points]]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0, 0}, {0.984808, 0.173648, 0.}, {1.9245, 0.515668, 0.}, {2.79053, 1.01567, 0.}, {3.55657, 1.65846, 0.}, {4.19936, 2.4245, 0.}}
> ```

```
ListPlot[Accumulate@
  Prepend[MapIndexed[N@Nest[r, #1, First[#2]] &, Differences@points], 
    First[points]][[All, {1, 2}]], AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}}, Frame -> True]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

the norm of the difference between consecutive vectors is conserved.

### Some fun

```
points2 = Array[{#, 0} &, 100];
anim = Table[
   ListLinePlot[
    Accumulate@
     Prepend[MapIndexed[
       N@Nest[RotationTransform[x Degree], #1, First[#2]] &, 
       Differences@points2], First[points2]]
    , AspectRatio -> 1
    , PlotRange -> {{-50, 100}, {-50, 100}}
    ], {x, 0, 4, 0.1}];
Export["curl.GIF", anim]
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but will say `Nest` makes it a (exp?) slow algorithm. For 30 points, it's been (still) running for a few minutes. Also, seems to trace a spiral, is that expected from constant angle?

Comment: @alancalvitti, Definitely `Nest` is not an efficient way, I was just trying to build from the already defined `r` function using small and simple code. The shape is not a spiral, but the *arc* of a circle.

Comment: Have you tried your method on 20 points or so? Looks like a spiral. `N` and accumulating error?

Comment: @alancalvitti The animation is with 100 points. If it looks like a spiral to you, please post a link to an image.

Comment: @rhermans: You have animated Euler-Bernoulli Law. An elastic line curvature in proportion to the bending moment M. However my output shows all frames but no continuous action. Ctrl-Y on the group does not work.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to think about it is to iteratively bend the "line" of points as the program "moves" down the list.  "Moves" is accomplished with `Rest`.  The result regrettably has extra data that needs to be discarded, which is done with the `...[[All, 1]]` bit of code.

```
rot = N@NestList[
    Rest@RotationTransform[10 Degree, {0, 0, 1}, #1[[1]]][#1] &, 
    points, Length[points] - 1][[All, 1]]
(* {{0., 0., 0.}, {0.984808, 0.173648, 0.}, {1.9245, 0.515668, 0.},
    {2.79053, 1.01567, 0.}, {3.55657, 1.65846, 0.}, {4.19936, 2.4245, 0.}} *)
```

Check the output:

```
VectorAngle @@@ Partition[Differences[rot], 2, 1]
EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[Differences[rot], 2, 1]
(* {0.174533, 0.174533, 0.174533, 0.174533}
   {0.174311, 0.174311, 0.174311, 0.174311} *)

10. Degree
(* 0.174533 *)
```

**Update:** Same idea, but with `TranslationTransform` serving to move the position down the line of points and no extra data:

```
N@FoldList[
  Composition[
     RotationTransform[10 Degree, {0, 0, 1}],
     TranslationTransform[#2]][#1] &,
  First[points],
  Differences[points]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Some days ago,I look at a python's module called turtle.And I think weather we can simulate the behavier of some functions in turtle.

First,I define some pre-function:

```
initial[position_, th_] :=  
Module[{θ = th, pos = position}, 
left := Function[theta, θ = θ + theta];
right := Function[theta, θ = θ - theta];
forward := 
Function[r, pos = pos + r*{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}; 
Sow[pos];]];
```

Or use the faster version for pre-function:

```
initial[position_, th_] := 
Module[{θ = th, pos = position}, 
left  :=  θ += # &;
right :=  θ -= # &;
forward := (pos += #*{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]};
Sow[pos];) &];
```

And then,I use the following code:

```
points = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}};
(* calculate the distance between these points *)
pre = Norm /@ Differences[points];
pos = First@points; θ = 0;       (*  initial conditions  *)
initial[pos, θ];(* use the initial function to set the conditions *)
point = Reap[Do[forward[pre[[i]]]; left[10 Degree], {i, 1, Length@pre}]][[2, 1]];
ListLinePlot[point /. {a__} -> {pos, a}, Mesh -> All]
```

[image]

Ok! Done...

Using this code to draw Koch curve maybe easy:
(the mechanism can look at the site [Recursion about Drawing Fractals](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/recursion.html))

```
Koch[order_, size_] := 
If[order == 0, forward[size], Koch[order - 1, size/3]; left[Pi/3];
Koch[order - 1, size/3]; right[2 Pi/3];
Koch[order - 1, size/3]; left[Pi/3]; Koch[order - 1, size/3];];
(*if order is 6,the graphics can be draw like this*)
initial[{0, 0}, 0]; (*  initial conditions  *)
point = Reap[Koch[6, 3]][[2, 1]];
Graphics[Line[point /. {a__} -> {{0, 0}, a}]]
```

[image]

Comment: `AppendTo` becomes increasingly slow as the length of `l` increases.  For performance you should consider refactoring this to use `Sow` and `Reap` or at least linked lists instead. +1 nevertheless.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you for your suggestions.Now,well done!I use `Sow` and `Reap` instead of `AppendTo` and I use local variables instead of globe variables.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to maintain the original distances between points I would also suggest the following:

```
points1 = 
  points = Most /@ {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0}, {4, 0,
       0}, {5, 0, 0}};
l = Length[points]; n = 1; While[n++; n <= l ,
 points[[n ;;]] = 
  RotationTransform[10 Degree, points[[n - 1]]][#] & /@ points[[n ;;]]];
ListPlot[{points1, points}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes maintaining the same distance between the points is important as this shows how a series of straight links curls and is closer to what I wanted to achieve.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach (to simplify i give a 2D solution - your problem is in 2D - but it can be easily extended in 3D) :

```
(* the coordinates of the first point *)
ori = {0, 0};

(* the initial angles between the succesive points *)
angles = {0, 0, 0, 0}

(* the function to build the coordinates from the angles *)
mkpts[ang_] := FoldList[(#1 + {Cos@#2, Sin@#2}) &, ori, Rest@FoldList[Plus, 0, ang]];
```

Some examples:

1/The initial straight line :

```
ListPlot[mkpts[angles], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

2/ 10 degrees relative rotation

```
ListPlot[mkpts[angles + 10. Degree], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

3/ For anything else you just define the angles :

```
ListPlot[mkpts[angles + {45, -45, -90, 90} Degree], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `AnglePath[]` is now built-in, here's a rather compact `Manipulate[]` for curling points:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[Line[AnglePath[N[ConstantArray[ϕ, n]]]], 
                    Frame -> True, PlotRange -> n],
           {{n, 2, "segments:"}, 2, 10, 1},
           {{ϕ, 0, "angle:"}, Experimental`AngularSlider[Dynamic[ϕ]] &}, 
           ControlPlacement -> Right]
```

[image: curling points]