# Implementing AnglePath in Mathematica 10.0

Tags: version-10, geometry

Does anyone have an implementation for `AnglePath` (see [`AnglePath` Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnglePath.html) and [example usage](http://blog.wolfram.com/2015/05/21/new-in-the-wolfram-language-anglepath/)) in *Mathematica* 10.0?

Comment: The classical procedure involved the elegant use of `FoldList[]`.

Comment: Can you point me in the direction of where I can read about the "classical procedure"? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: To start you off: `myAnglePath[list_?MatrixQ] := Composition[Through, {Re, Im}] /@ FoldList[Plus, 0, #1 Exp[I #2] & @@@ list]` corresponds to the second usage in the function listing you have. For the fourth usage, replace `0` with `x + I y`…

Comment: Maybe [Make a series of points curl](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63938/19960) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first usage, with an input list `t` of angles, I used:

```
anglePath[t_?VectorQ] := 
   With[{a = Accumulate[t]}, 
        Join[{{0., 0.}}, Accumulate[Transpose[{Cos[a], Sin[a]}]]]]
```

For the second usage, with an input matrix of `{r,t}` pairs, I used:

```
anglePath[t_?MatrixQ] :=
   With[{a = Accumulate[t[[All, 2]]]}, 
        Join[{{0., 0.}},
             Accumulate[t[[All, 1]]*Transpose[{Cos[a], Sin[a]}]]]
   ]
```

Borrowing from the blog post:

```
Graphics[
  {Thick,
   MapIndexed[{ColorData["SandyTerrain", First[#2]/110], Line[#]} &, 
      Partition[anglePath[Table[{r,119.4*Degree},{r,0,1.1,0.01}]],
                2, 1]]},
   Background -> Black]
```

[image: angle path graphic]

Answer (score 3):

I managed to figure out how to re-implement `AnglePath[]`, since I needed to do something turtle-related for a friend, and I still do not have access to a computer with version 10.

First, the special cases:

```
anglePath[steps_] := anglePath[{{0, 0}, 0}, steps]
anglePath[p_?VectorQ, steps_] := anglePath[{p, 0}, steps]
anglePath[alpha0_, steps_] := anglePath[{{0, 0}, alpha0}, steps]
anglePath[{p_?VectorQ, v_?VectorQ}, steps_] :=
          anglePath[{p, Arg[#1 + I #2] & @@ v}, steps]
anglePath[palpha_, steps_?VectorQ] := 
          anglePath[palpha, Transpose[PadLeft[{steps}, {2, Automatic}, 1]]]
```

I chose to implement the general form through the use of a compiled function; thus, the general case is merely a wrapper for the compiled function `apc`:

```
anglePath[{v_?VectorQ, alpha0_}, steps_?MatrixQ] := apc[v, alpha0, steps]
```

Here's the compiled function that does all the magic:

```
apc = Compile[{{v0, _Real, 1}, {alpha0, _Real}, {steps, _Real, 2}},
              Module[{alpha = alpha0, z = v0[[1]] + I v0[[2]], pb, r, theta},
                     pb = Internal`Bag[{z}];
                     Scan[({r, theta} = #; Internal`StuffBag[pb,
                           z += r Exp[I (alpha += theta)]]) &, steps];
                     {Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ Internal`BagPart[pb, All]],
              RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

In my opinion, the use of the complex number formulation is both mathematically and programmatically elegant. (An opinion I've held ever since reading [Zwikker's book](http://books.google.com/books?id=25tMEYTik-AC).) I did mention the possibility of using `Fold[]` instead; I'll leave the writing of that version of `apc` as an exercise for the interested reader.

Here are two examples. The first one is the generation of the so-called "dragon curve":

```
Graphics[Line[anglePath[KroneckerSymbol[-1, Range[2048]] π/2]]]
```

[image: dragon curve]

(There is an equivalent example in the docs.)

The second example is the use of `anglePath[]` to generate the [spiral of Theodorus](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66969):

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Black], Polygon[PadRight[#, {3, 2}]] & /@ 
          Partition[anglePath[{{1, 0}, π/2},
                              Prepend[ArcCot[Sqrt[Range[15]]], 0]], 2, 1]}]
```

[image: spiral of Theodorus, first try]