# How to make this tree using AnglePath?

Tags: graphics, function-construction, fractals

[Here](https://trinket.io/python/62ca928524) is a Python turtle code for making a fractral tree, I had translation it to mathematica code(see [Make a series of points curl](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63938/make-a-series-of-points-curl/73527#73527)):

```
Clear["`*"];

initial[position_, th_] :=
  Module[{θ = th, pos = position},
   left := θ += # &;
   right := θ -= # &;
   forward := (pos += #*{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}; Sow[pos];) &;
   backward := (pos -= #*{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}; Sow[pos];) &;
   ];

tree[n_] :=
  If[n > 5,
   forward[n];
   (*right[20 Degree];*)
   left[-20 Degree];
   tree[n - 15];
   left[40 Degree];
   tree[n - 15];
   (*right[20 Degree];*)
   left[-20 Degree];
   backward[n]
   ];

initial[{0, 0}, Pi/2];(*initial conditions*)
point = Reap[tree[15 5]][[2, 1]];
Graphics[Line[point]]
```

I found `AnglePath` would be better for this, but I don't know how to programmingly do this.

```
Graphics@Line@AnglePath[{{0,0},-(π/2)},{{45,180 °},{30,-20 °},  
{15,-20 °},{15,180 °},{15,-140 °},{15,180 °},{30,-20 °},
{30,-140 °},{15,-20 °},{15,180 °},{15,-140 °},{15,180 °},{30,-20 °},{45,-20 °}}]
```

Comment: Your Mathematica code works to produce a simple tree. What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wants to get the function which does this for arbitrary n.  I'm not sure `AnglePath` is the best function for this, since this involves a bunch of retracing.  But it's probably better than that somewhat scary and non-local code.

Comment: You created it? You should add reference https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63938/make-a-series-of-points-curl/73527#73527

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you just want to translate those commands into what `AnglePath` wants, taking it account the current orientation.  Forward is just going forward a distance $n$ with no rotation.  Left is just rotating some many degrees over no distance.  Because we don't want a extra level of list at each stage, we use `Apply` to retrun `Sequence` object at each stage.  Also note that since the total rotation of each tree is 180 degrees, we must add 180 degrees in the middle to keep the orientation.

```
tree[n_] := If[n > 5,
  Sequence @@ {{n, 0}, {0, -20 Degree}, 
    tree[n - 15], {0, 220 Degree},
    tree[n - 15], {n, -20 Degree}}, Sequence @@ {}]

makeTree[θ0_, n_] := 
 Graphics@Line@AnglePath[{{0, θ0}, tree[n]}]

makeTree[Pi/2, 75]
```

Comment: What tripped me up in trying to translate the Python code is that the turtle backtracks (just like in Logo!) and `AnglePath[]` does not without generating an overlapping segment.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, if you saw my comment on the question, I don't think either `AnglePath` or the original code are particularly good.  I'm certainly not avoiding doubled edges.  I just offer this as a more or less direct translation.